# Why am I getting a double response from this AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

Can anyone explain why I seem to be getting a double success response from this AJAX request using Bootstrap modals?

I am getting back `testtest` instead of `test`.

I'm pretty sure from looking at the console there is only 1 request being made and I've checked the scripts are only being loaded once.

**Button triggers script:**

```
<a href="#" class="openNotesModal" data-note="<?=$view->action('thisNote',$RA,$question['q_ref'],$bID);?>"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt">Notes</a>
```

**Javascript**(A bit convoluted from trying previous fixes found on S.O.)

```
function openNotesModal() {
  $('#notesModal').modal({
    keyboard: false,
    backdrop: 'static'
  });
}

$('.openNotesModal').click(function() {
  openNotesModal();
});

$('#notesModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: $('.openNotesModal').attr('data-note'),
    success: function(response) {
      $('#notesModal #theNote').val(response);
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
});
```

**AJAX request routed to this method**

```
public function action_thisNote($ra,$qID,$bID = null)
{
    echo "test";
}
```

Should return *'test'* but returns *'testtest'* instead

Comment: What if you console.log something before the ajax request executes?

Comment: I've tried this - I logged 'modal open' directly before the ajax request. It definitely only logs once.

Comment: Good deal, just double checking.

Comment: There was an answer below now deleted that suggested the problem could be using echo instead of return.

My (limited!) understanding is that you can use echo for a response for AJAX use. I've tried changing using 'return "test";` instead, but this seems to break the request altogether.  Sure I'm missing something obvious here!

Comment: Open up the page without the Ajax call and see if you see it duplicated (or look at the request in the network tab)

Comment: @epascarello - do you mean open the page the AJAX call is targeting? This is just a PHP controller file. I'm using Concrete5 CMS, the url  routes the request to the `action_thisNote` method.

Comment: Yes, Ajax request is no different than a HTTP request.

Comment: Ok yes I've hit the url directly and I do see the incorrect doubled `testtest` response. Not sure what this tells me, I guess we know for sure the AJAX request itself is only being made once.

Comment: I'm just drilling into this a bit more, but I think that maybe the problem is arising from Concrete5's action_ prefixed methods being reserved for form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the method my AJAX call was routed to has fixed this. The issue is actually related to Concrete5 CMS which I'm building on top of.

Controller methods `prefixed action_` are routed via urls for use in form submission. I think they auto-redirect after a form is submitted and this was causing problems with my AJAX request in the bootstrap modal. Calling `exit();` function after returning my value stops the redirect and any other onward processing by the CMS.

*Thanks to @epascarello in the comments above for leading me to the fix by suggesting the obvious of checking the URL outside of AJAX request helping to isolate the issue.*

Fixed PHP function/method:

```
public function action_thisNote($ra,$qID,$bID = null)
{
    echo 'test';
    exit();
}
```